# How can I implement two memoization in one function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, memoization

I wish to solve a problem with a recursive function using two memoization dictionaries, but I'm not sure how to execute this idea.

From what I have learned, when using just one memoization dicionary, the code structure looks similar. For example, to solve Fibonacci number:

```
def fib_mem(n,mem=None):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    if mem == None:
        mem = {}
    if n not in mem:
        mem[n] = fib_mem(n-1,mem) + fib_mem(n-2,mem)
    return mem[n]
```

What should I add to the code to use two memoization dicitionaries? What should I add to the `def` line, and in the recursive calls?

my problem:

`list = [(16, 1, 4), (17, 2, 9), (3, 17, 10)]`

which `list [i][0]` is the values. I should get the maximum possible combination values, considering two limiting factors given: `list[i][1]` and `list[i][2]`.

Comment: Why would you want two dictionaries?

Comment: What do you think having a second dict will improve?

Comment: Note that the conventional way to implement memoization is with a **decorator**, and you should test for `None` by **identity** - `if mem is None`.

Comment: thank you for replying so fast. in my problem I got two Limiting factors, which I try to separate to 2 different problems, and get one of the returning values by using minimum function.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided an example of your *actual problem*, then, showing a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your current code and describing the issues with it.

Comment: That's really not a very clear example.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fathom why you would want to use two different dictionaries, but I'd use a decorator

```
from functools import wraps

def memoize_two_dict(func):
    dict1 = {}
    dict2 = {}

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, use_dict1=True):
        targs = tuple(args)
        if use_dict1:
            if targs not in dict1:
                dict1[targs] = func(*args)
            return dict1[targs]
        else:
            if targs not in dict2:
                dict2[targs] = func(*args)
            return dict2[targs]
    return wrapper

@memoize_two_dict
def myfunction(args):
    ...

# Uses the two different dictionaries
myfunction(1, use_dict1=False)
myfunction(1)
```